# Сохранение пропорций background для виджетов

Tags: android, android-drawable

Чтоб приложение выглядело красиво, я расставляю View-элементы поверх background'а в родительском layout'е, в итоге создаётся целостная картина.
Но всё выглядит правильно только с соотношением сторон 16/9, на других же девайсах background растягивается и перестаёт соответствовать положению View-элементов.
 Хотя я даже не понимаю, почему он растягивается, ведь в layout widh и height стоят значения wrap_content.

Я хочу, чтоб он сохранял размер и обрезался по краям в случае необходимости.

Comment: в каков `Layout` все это уложено?

Comment: @metalurgus , relative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772572/1568530 этот ответ должен вам помочь. Нужно будет только переделать для `RelativeLayout`

Comment: В дефолтных виджетах бэкграунд всегда умещается целиком, соответственно растягиваясь или сжимаясь под размеры виджета. Свойства `wrap_content` распространяются на контент виджета (что следует из названия), а не его фон.

Comment: @metalurgus, что нужно писать вместо R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout_aspectRatioWidth
R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout_aspectRatioHeight?

Comment: запишите туда просто желаемое соотношение - `mAspectRatioWidth = 9; mAspectRatioHeight = 16`, или наоборот, как вам надо

Comment: Я вот погуглил вместо вас еще, и нашел вообще библиотеку, чтобы вообще ничего не надо было делать: https://github.com/devsoulwolf/Android-RatioLayout

Comment: @metalurgus Что то я так понял, автору просто нужно разместить картинку без искажений и отрезать лишнее, что не входит в размеры виджета

Comment: @pavlofff , вот да. И что ж делать с этим? Совет metalurgus поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу абстрактный пример.

Некоторая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/crop_background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

В качестве фона для контейнера указан bitmap-xml - crop_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background_image"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:tileMode="disabled"/>
```

где *background_image* - картинка с желаемым бэкграундом, например в .png

Если указать для битмапа свойство `gravity`, то итоговое изображение будет обрезаться границами виджета. Позиционирование для обрезки можно задать с помощью параметров гравити, так в примере выше:

`android:gravity="top|left"` - изображение располагать от левого верхнего края. Все что правее и ниже не войдет в границы виджета - будет обрезано.

Другой пример `android:gravity="center"` - изображение располагать от центра, все, что выше, ниже, правее и левее не войдет в границы виджета - будет обрезано.

Другие значения с которыми вы можете эксперементировать, чтобы получить нужный эффект( можно комбинировать через |)- `top`,  `bottom`,  `left`,  `right`,  `center_vertical`,`fill_vertical`,  `center_horizontal`,  `fill_horizontal`, `center`,  `fill`,  `clip_vertical`,  `clip_horizontal`.

`android:tileMode="disabled"` - параметр заполнения. В данном случае отключено. Изображение не будет дублироваться, зеркалироваться и пр. для заполнения всего объема.

Результат:

[image: scrn]

Используемое фоновое изображение:

[image: scrn]

PS: При просмотре в визуальном редакторе Android Studio после каждого изменения необходимо делать *Build -> Rebuild Project*, чтобы увидеть внесенные в гравити изменения.

Comment: Да, я пробовал создавать xml с битмапом, но видимо писал там вместо gravity какую-то дичь. Но вы как всегда помогли мне разобраться. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать следующим образом:

```
 <FrameLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/your_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Все-таки проще было бы решать проблему увидев ваш layout xml

Comment: я думал над чем-то подобным, но всё никак не решался. Попробовал. На разрешении 768X1280 со scaleType "centerCrop" изображение прижалось к левому углу, оставив справа белую полоску вместо того чтоб увеличиться обрезаться.

Comment: @iamsolame Вам должен помочь атрибут `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` для `ImageView`/ Так же [эта статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php)

Comment: @pavlofff, да я из этой статейки то и взял scaleType "centerCrop" . Но что-то плохо работает. Картинка то обрезается, но не полностью, белая полоска остаётся. От ViewBounds "true" картинка вообще перестала обрезаться

Comment: @iamsolame, не совсем понял "чтоб увеличиться обрезаться". Если вам надо, чтоб картинка была вписана в экран, то `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"`