# Фон в LinearLayout UI android

Tags: java, android

Есть скажем простой `LinearLayout`.
Мне нужно программно вывести загруженный объект `Bitmap` как фон этого `LinearLayout`.
Но не понимаю как это сделать программно ведь не один из методов не предназначен для `Bitmap`.

Если возникнет вдруг вопрос зачем `Bitmap` на `LinearLayout` то затем чтобы фон был на весь экран чего я не смог добиться от `ImageView`. Если есть альтернативы то я вас выслушаю.

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488086/177345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно именно программно устанавливать, то попробуйте как-то так.

`BitmapDrawable(obj)` конвертирует `Bitmap` в `Drawable`

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
(view).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

На основе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466992/9007098)

Comment: Спасибо большое