# Как обеспечить статичность фона?

Tags: android

Как известно при использовании свойства background у любого контейнера (layout) фоновое изображение автоматически подгоняется под его размер. особенно это заметно если на экране есть поле ввода и при появлении клавиатуры контейнер сжимается по высоте.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при появлении клавиатуры размер контейнера оствался постоянным и был равен размеру экрана?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488086/177345

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам.

Нужно внутри нужного тега `<Activity>` в манифесте указать:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```