# Нужно отключить растяжение фона в Android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Имеется `ScrollView` на котором установлен `RelativeLayout` имеющий фон атрибутом `android:background`. Этот фон растягивается вниз. Есть ли какой-то атрибут для отключения растяжения? Фон имеет высоту около `2000dp`, его мне точно хватит для установления всех элементов. Так же я использую RelativeLayout из библиотеки Carbon для расширенных функий.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large">
            
            <!-- some buttons -->
            
        </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>
        
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: android:scaleType в помощь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488086/177345 ?

Comment: android:scaleType не помог. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488086/177345 так же не помог, так как у меня не изображение.

Comment: вам легче под низ подложить ImagrView с вашей картинкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло удаление фона на `RelativeLayout` и установление изображения как отдельный `View`.